# Selecting one row from multiple similar ones based on most recent date

Tags: sql, duplicates, teradata

I have a table structured like this:

customer_name, dateA, dateB, dateC

```
DateA<=DateB<=DateC.
```

Customers are sometimes listed multiple times with different dates for each DateA, DateB, and DateC.

So if my data looks like:

```
X, 10/01, 10/02, 10/03
X, 10/04, 10/05, 10/06
X, 10/05, 10/07, 10/08
Y, 10/01, 10/05, NULL
Y, 10/01, 10/06, NULL
Z, 10/02, NULL,  NULL
Z, 10/03, 10/04, NULL
```

I want:

```
X, 10/05, 10/07, 10/08
Y, 10/01, 10/06, NULL
Z, 10/03, 10/04, NULL
```

In other words I want one row per customer that is the furthest along in the process where dateA, dateB, and dateC are milestones in the process.

If two rows are the same customer and at the same milestone, I'd like to select only the one with the furthest date.

I'm using Teradata 14.10.

Fairly new to SQL so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Sorry: we're using Teradata.

Comment: Which Teradata release? Which rows should be returned if dateC is NULL?

Comment: We're using Teradata 14.10. I updated the question to provide some more details. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return your expected result:

```
select * from tab
qualify
   row_number()
   over (partition by customer_name
         order by dateC desc, dateB desc, dateA desc) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great! I will have to study this command. Wish I could upvote you.